# Map vs Mapply - Unexpected behavior with Mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I have a list of functions and a list of dataframes (all functions return a plot object) . I want to apply the i<sup>th</sup> function to the i<sup>th</sup> dataset. I tried using mapply for this, as shown below:

```
mapply(function(f,x) f(x), list_functions, list_datasets)
```

When I try this, I get something unexpected. This is how the output looks like:

```
 data        List,7 List,3      List,7
 layers      List,1 List,3      List,2
 scales      ?      ?           ?     
 mapping     List,3 List,3      List,4
 theme       List,0 List,0      List,0
 coordinates List,1 List,1      List,1
 facet       List,7 List,1      List,1
 plot_env    ?      ?           ?     
 labels      List,3 List,4      List,4
```

While, off course, what I wanted was a list of plot objects to be returned.

I then tried this:

```
Map(function(f,x) f(x), list_functions, list_datasets)
```

And this time the output that I get is exactly what I want - a list of plots.

So, while the issue is resolved, I am quite keen to figure out why `mapply` behaved the way it did.

Any pointers?

Thanks & Merry x-mas!!

Comment: Add a `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to your `mapply`.....

Comment: And please read the help file

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior of `mapply` is to simplify the output whenever possible. If you want to override that behavior, add a `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to your command.

This demonstrates the behavior (I don't have access to your functions or data, so I can't recreate what you've shared here).

Since the output is something that can be simplified, the result would be a matrix:

```
> mapply(rep, 1:4, 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    1    2    3    4
```

Override that behavior:

```
> mapply(rep, 1:4, 4, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 4 4
```

---

You should still be able to access items from your output with the standard `[row, col]` type of approach you would use with any matrix.